# Корректное завершение spring boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduler

Есть приложение на spring boot

```
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Application {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Application.class);

    @Value("${executor}")
    private String executorName;

    @Autowired
    public void setExecutorName(ApplicationContext context) {
        context.getBean(executorName);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

которое запускает Scheduler

```
@Service("exporter")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class ExecutorExporterService {

    @Value("${topicName}")
    String topicName;

    @Autowired
    EntityRepository entityRepository;

    @Autowired
    ConsumerKafka consumerKafka;

    @Transactional
    @Scheduled(fixedRateString = "${timeInterval}")
    public void runExecutor() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Set<ConsumerRecord> consumerRecords = consumerKafka.consumeKafka(Collections.singletonList(topicName));

        List<Person> persons = consumerRecords.stream().map(record -> (Person) record.value()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        entityRepository.saveAll(persons);

        consumerKafka.commitSyncConsumer();
        consumerKafka.closeConsumer();
        System.out.println(persons);
    }
}
```

запускаю `mvn spring-boot:start`

пытаюсь остановить: `mvn spring-boot:stop`

выдает:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.2.4.RELEASE:stop (default-cli) on project leantegra_importer: Spring application lifecycle JMX bean not found (fork is null). Could not stop application gracefully: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication -> [Help 1]
```

И приложение не останавливается.

Как сделать корректную остановку? И возможно ли это сделать по `Ctrl C`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данной статье есть несколько вариантов

[клик](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown)

Способ №1:

```
    @RestController
public class ShutdownController implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext context;

    @PostMapping("/shutdownContext")
    public void shutdownContext() {
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).close();
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
        this.context = ctx;

    }
}
```

и через curl `curl -X POST localhost:port/shutdownContext`

Способ №2:

```
SpringApplicationBuilder app = new 
SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
  .web(WebApplicationType.NONE);
app.build().addListeners(new 
ApplicationPidFileWriter("./bin/shutdown.pid"));
   app.run();
```

В консоли `kill $(cat ./bin/shutdown.pid)`

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/443453)

Comment: @tutankhamun сейчас допишу